# How to decide which angular custom directive to use

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering whether we have any scenarios as there are four types of custom directives: Element, Attribute, Comments and Class, which one to choose when creating a custom directive

Comment: It depends on your requirement

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a very popular [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) written by John Papa 
comments and classes are best to be avoided.
Generally EA is ok. 
 If you want to be more specific use:

Element when creating a standalone directive (with its own html template) and

Attribute when creating a directive that adds functionality to existing html